# iPhone (or generic iOS) whole partition dump

Tags: iphone, security, ios, computer-forensics

I was reading

> iOS Forensic Analysis: for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch
>   [here on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233427)

I can't find out/understand how to get a whole dump of the iOS device paritions on a unjailbroken device. I think it necessary to use usb in such way (maybe like [phoneview](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) does) but i didn't find anything online.
Am i ignoring something?

Comment: Praying to Steve this is not doable on uncompromised devices.

Comment: This belongs on Apple.SE

Answer (score 0):

Tools such as Elcomsoft and Lantern2 will do it.

Answer (score 0):

A number of commercial forensic tools will do it by utilizing the same sort of exploits that are used to jailbreak the phones. In general the tools need to be updated for each new release. With an iPhone 4 the phone needs to be unlocked, otherwise apple's data at rest uenryption will prevent you from getting much.